# What motivation is there for Sylow's Theorems?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to know what kind of results or consequences which motivate Sylow's Theorems.
I mean for one who doesn't even know about statement of Sylow's Theorem, can motivate for it by some other consequences, like in linear algebra $1$ dimensional invariant subspace will directly motivate one to eigen values.

Comment: It is the strongest converse of Lagrange's Theorem that holds for all finite groups.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for applications, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60598/applications-for-p-sylow-subgroups-theorem/60628 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406315/atypical-use-of-sylow.

However, I think the Sylow theorems are not motivated by their consequences, but simply by curiosity: how far can we have a converse to Lagrange's theorem?

In an abelian group $G$, for every $d$ dividing $|G|$ there is a subgroup of order $d$ (so the converse of Lagrange's theorem works fully).

In $A_4$, of order $12$, there is no subgroup of order $6$. So the converse of Lagrange's theorem does not work fully.

Cauchy's theorem shows for a prime divisor $p$ of the order of a finite group, there's a subgroup of order $p$. So the converse of Lagrange's theorem is always true for prime factors of the order.

The Sylow theorems, or at least the *first* one, shows the converse of Lagrange's theorem is true for the maximal prime powers.  Do you find that to be boring?
In fact there are subgroups of every prime power dividing the size of the group, not just the maximal prime powers, but some other parts of the Sylow theorems besides existence are often not true of the $p$-subgroups that are not $p$-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Do you have the proof of first sylow thm which have remarkable property of prime number;i mean prime number has (xyz) property  thats why we can proceed further for our goal of  finding of subgroup with given prime divisor

Comment: The Sylow theorems are about subgroups of *maximal* prime power order, not of prime order.  You can read multiple proofs of the first Sylow theorem in books or online to find one that you like more than others.  For a proof of that theorem, what's special about a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ having order equal to the *largest* power of a prime $p$ that divides $|G|$ is that (i) $|H|$ has $p$-power order and (ii) the index $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$ is not divisible by $p$.  These aspects will come up in a proof of the 1st Sylow theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Some vague comments:

In group theory, you want to understand the "structure" of a group $G$. One part of this structure is the subgroup structure. If you understand all the subgroups of $G$, you would have a pretty good understanding the group.

In general this is too difficult - you are not even able to classify all finite groups, let alone all subgroups of all finite groups. But we would like to know something.

Suppose that $G$ is finite. There are some general results about the subgroups of $G$. One of the first things you learn is Lagrange's theorem: the order of a subgroup $H \leq G$ divides the order of $G$.

That places some restrictions on what the subgroups could be, and there are various other results in that direction. But existence of subgroups and finding them - that can be more difficult.

Sylow's theorem, which is great since it works for all finite groups, gives you the existence of groups of certain order. (In general: if $d \mid |G|$, it is not always true that $G$ contains a subgroup of order $d$.)

So let $|G| = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_t^{k_t}$ be the prime factorization of $|G|$. Sylow's theorem tells you that there exists subgroups $P_i \leq G$ with $|P_i| = p_i^{k_i}$. Furthermore, any two subgroups with order $p_i^{k_i}$ are conjugate in $G$, so the structure of $P_i$ is unique.

Without going into detail, if you want to study a finite group $G$, often one of the first things you would like to look at are the Sylow subgroups. These (and more generally the subgroups of prime power order) have a great deal of control over the structure of $G$. Once you understand the Sylow subgroups and how they behave in $G$, you should already have some idea about the structure of $G$.

Comment: @spinPlz read my full reply ; as you mentioned "you want to understand the "structure" of a group".what is exactly required for one to understand structure.as group is basically set with specific function from set*set to set :so what i know is if i have this function (basically binary operator)then i believe i have full structure of group: for example in topology on some set if i have collection of open sets then i can say i know every topological property of that set .for given linear transformation if i have only image of basis element then i can say i have entire l.t as (read 2nd cmnt)

Comment: it is eventually function.here in group theory what one mean by understand structure of group:what is required detail to have structure of group and in your sense if one have structure of group then he will every detail of that group?plz describe in as much detail as possible;

Comment: Well say you are given some matrix, and you know its entries. Does that mean you understand completely the properties of the linear transformation? I don't think it is the case, just knowing the matrix does not mean it is easy to find out the Jordan normal form, eigenvalues, etc.. So similarly for a group, just because you know what the binary operation $*: G \times G \rightarrow G$ is, it does not mean everything about the group is obvious. For the structure you would like to understand things like subgroups, normal subgroups, conjugacy classes, automorphisms, to give some basic examples.

Comment: The binary operation $*: G \times G \rightarrow G$ of course determines all the group-theoretical properties of $G$. But trying to understand the properties of $G$ via the multiplication table is the worst way to do it, and not what group theory is really about

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great application of Sylow's first theorem: the ever useful *Cauchy's theorem*.   It states that if $p$ prime divides the order of $G$, then there's an element of order $p$.

Proof:

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup.  Take a non-identity element $g\in P$.  Then the order of $g$ is $p^\alpha $ for some $\alpha $.  Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$.  By the theory of cyclic groups,  it contains an element of order $p.□$